# Svelte loading indicator for a synchronous method

Tags: svelte

I have a long running synchronous method call in my svelte app. I want to show a spinner or somesuch while it's working. I would have thought I could do it like the following:

```
<script>
    import {doIt} from "./thingDoer.js"
    let showLoading = false;
    function doTheThing() {
        showLoading = true;
        doIt();
        showLoading = false;
    }
</script>

{#if showLoading}
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
{:else}
    <button on:click={doTheThing}>Do the Thing</button>
{/if}
```

but that does not show the loading indicator. I also thought this was maybe what the `tick` function was for, but that's not any better:

```
<script>
    import {doIt} from "./thingDoer.js"
    import {tick} from "svelte"
    let showLoading = false;
    async function doTheThing() {
        showLoading = true;
        await tick();
        doIt();
        showLoading = false;
    }
</script>

{#if showLoading}
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
{:else}
    <button on:click={doTheThing}>Do the Thing</button>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a synchronous operation that will block the main thread and thus rendering of the page. If possible you should avoid this, as it makes the page completely unresponsive, e.g. by using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API).

If for some reason that is not possible/feasible here, you have to not only wait for the DOM tree to be updated, which `tick` should do, but also the browser to render the page because as soon as the synchronous long running task starts, nothing will change.

One way to do that is the *double RAF*, this should probably make the `tick` obsolete, but you could just keep that in there.

```js
async function doTheThing() {
    showLoading = true;
    await tick();
    requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        doIt();
        showLoading = false;
    }));
}
```

The callback to [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is executed *before* the next repaint, so by nesting calls, you wait for one repaint to happen.

You could also *promisify* this, which makes the code a bit more self-documenting:

```js
function repaint() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
        requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(() => resolve()))
    );
}

async function doTheThing() {
    showLoading = true;
    await tick();
    await repaint();
    doIt();
    showLoading = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Svelte provides the {#await} block you can use to wait for the promise (i.e. `doIt` from `./thingDoer.js`) to resolve.
Using your query, approach could be like this:

```js
<script>
import {doIt} from "./thingDoer.js";
let result_from_doIt = null; //Initial state set to null for result from doIt
</script>
```

Use {#await} to handle `doIt`. In code below; I'm using {#await} block to indicate `doIt` function is running;

```html
<button on:click={()=>{
    result_from_doIt = doIt() //Run doIt()
}}>
    {#await result_from_doIt}
  <span>loading</span>
{:then result_from_doIt}
    <span>Do It</span>
{:catch error}
  <span>Error</span> 
{/await}
</button>
```

If you want to use the {#await} block to load your data, see..

```html
{#if result_from_doIt}
    {#await result_from_doIt}
  <p>loading</p>
{:then item}
    <p>{JSON.stringify(item)}</p>
{:catch error}
  <p style="color: red">{error.message}</p>
{/await}
{/if}
```

Do check out `svelte` documentation on the await block; https://svelte.dev/examples/await-blocks